# Error when retrieving emails from Dynamics 365 using KingswaySoft SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-365, kingswaysoft

I'm extracting all email records from a Dynamics 365 instance using KingswaySoft CRM Source Component.

The error I'm getting indicates that there is something going wrong when the KingswaySoft Source Component tries to find the relation from the email to the party. The problem I have is that I do not have any identifier pointing me to which email has this broken/null reference relation.

Is there someway for me to get the activityids of the records that throws this error?

`[email [339]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failed to process the output value for CDS/CRM field 'email_activity_parties' (or one of its related fields). System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary. (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v21.2.0.31501 - DtsDebugHost, v13.0.6300.2)".`

I have tried to eliminate the fields that I know are related a party - to, from cc and bcc, but I'm still getting this error. I assume that the KingswaySoft Source Component always checks the relation even though I'm not actively extract those fields.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please reach out to us for this issue. We might need access to the environment in order to conduct a proper analysis of the issue - for your reference, we don't have a reproduce of this issue.

Comment: In addition, this error is likely only happening to a connection manager that uses the WebAPI service endpoint. The error should disappear if you switch to the SOAP 2011 service endpoint.

Comment: Switching from WebAPI to SOAP2011 resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply KingswaySoft.

Switching from Service Endpoint: WebAPI to SOAP2011 fixed the issue